# Python: how to pass a index range as parameter

Tags: python

I know this is possible, is there any other way to pass something like 0:100 ?

```
a=range(1000)

ohlc.C.ix[a]
```

Thank you!

Comment: while someone gave you the correct answer, you should edit your question to clarify that you want to be able to do `list[parameter]` directly with no manipulation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pass a `slice` object.

```
a = slice(0, 100)
```

Comment: I think this is the way to go and won't print out the whole range, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Is `ohlc.C.ix` a function? Are you using python 2 or python 3?

If you are just wanting it to post 0 - 100 and you are using python 2 do `a[0:100]`
or if you are using python three do `list(a)[0:100]`

if `ohlc.C.ix` is a function then do `ohcl.c.ix(a)`

if `ohlc.C.ix` is a `list` then you will probably want to do `a = slice(0, 100)` but your question is so vague. I don't really understand what you want.

Answer (score 0):

What came to my mind that you pass a tuple with your start and end and do whatever you want in your method

a = (1,100)

Answer (score 0):

The question seems a bit unclear but you could have a method that takes two parameters: the start and end of the range. So in you example you could have:

```
def doSomethingWithRange(start, end)
   #do something
```